# Python dictionaries: function to populate dictionary overwriting earlier call of the same function

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a data structure organizing certain demographic stats in a dictionary where the initial key is the region (The Americas, Europe etc.). The value of each of these is a dictionary which contains the key:value country code : data value. The function I've written to achieve this seems to work, but on being called a second time in the same script and assigned a different variable name it not only returns the expected dictionary for that call but overwrites the dictionary produced in the first call.

I've tried creating an empty dictionary (`dictionaryName = {}`) for the variable before calling the function (`dictionaryName = functionCall()` ). I've also tried making a copy of the dictionaries required as arguments for the function and passing in the copies rather than the originals, and returning a copy from the function rather than a modified version of the dictionary with blank values I was using as a template. In all cases the second function call still overwrites the variable created in/for the first.

These are the function calls:

```
orderedData1960 = insertDataIntoCategoryAndCodesDictionary(data1960, dictionaryOfRegionsAndCodes)
orderedData2013 = insertDataIntoCategoryAndCodesDictionary(data2013, dictionaryOfRegionsAndCodes)
```

This is the function itself:

```
def insertDataIntoCategoryAndCodesDictionary(dataSet, categoriesAndCodesDictionary):
    for category in categoriesAndCodesDictionary:
        updateData(categoriesAndCodesDictionary[category], dataSet)
    return categoriesAndCodesDictionary

def updateData(category, dataSet):
    for key in category:
        category.update({key: dataSet.get(key)})
```

`orderedData1960` and `orderedData2013` should end up as 2 different data sets in the same structure; the actual result at present is that they end up identical.

Comment: Your first function just returns the second parameter. This way `orderedData1960` and `orderedData2013` both just refer to `dictionaryOfRegionsAndCodes`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misinterpreted something. The problem is that your first function returns the second param, since you don't override it anywhere in the function.